# a-videosphere control mute

Tags: video, volume, aframe, mute

I want to create a landing page with a-videosphere 360 video but I want to load it muted ... or with the volume at 0 because it's annoying to get surprised by sound when you land on a site. But I don't know the command to "mute" and "unmute" the video. ( and or control the volume )

```
<video muted id="video" style="display:none" autoplay loop crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline webkit-playsinline>
<source type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" />
</video>

document.querySelector("#video").???();
```

Comment: Does `document.querySelector("#video").volume = 0.0;` work?

Comment: Ha ... it does ... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code already contains the correct attribute to load the video - 'muted'.

You can mute a video by getting a reference to it and then set it to muted or not muted in Javascript:

```js
vid = document.getElementById("myPath/myvideo.mp4");

//Mute video
vid.muted = true;

//Turn sound on 
vid.muted = false;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @Mick